Decoupling output of direct grid voltage class E amplifier
For a university project I'll implement some middle power (100 W) high frequency inverters (~500 kHz) with pulsed DC ~300 V DC output. The output current must be decoupled from the supplier grid due to possible ground leakage on the load which may trigger differential switches on my electrical cabinet, I need to reach decoupling like using a transformer (1:1 or similar) without using it because I can't wind hundreds ferrite transformers one by one. I was therefore looking for an inverter topology without transformer, with only inductor/capacitor, satisfying the following requirements:

Decoupling from grid: the output pins mustn't have a reference with earth potential or grid conductors, so in case of external contacts no leakage current should flow on earth conductor or grid conductors, like using an isolation transformer but without using it.

Ballasting function: I need to limit the power to ~100 W, but it can be easily obtained with a series inductor of proper reactance

Acceptable PF: not necessarily intended as active PF correction stadium, I only need to obtain PF > 0.7

Possibility of increasing voltage compared to input grid voltage: boost converter technique.


I was comparing the similarities of class E amplifier, active PFC circuit, and boost converter (DC-DC step-up), I was wondering if the above functions can coexist and if they guarantee decoupling from power source (not safety isolation obviously! ). The load is mainly resistive with a little capacity (~2 nF).


You seem to be talking about isolation, not decoupling. For example, the "RF Choke" is what would normally be called a decoupling element. As for the power supply, have you considered the standard topologies (flyback, forward)? If so, what about your application are they unsuitable for?

The concept of isolation is right, but without a transformer that guarantees galvanic isolation I don't know if it can still be called isolation. The classic boost converter topology is partially suitable for my purpose, but it performs only one of the functions I need. Although with some slight differences, boost converter circuit exactly follows the scheme of the class E amplifier, as well as the scheme of the active PFC, which is why I was asking if with a single circuit it was possible to exploit several advantages at the same time (voltage increase, PF correction, supplier grid isolation)
